# Alphabet Checksum

Tags: code-golf, string, alphabet

#### Your task

Given a string of lowercase letters, output the "alphabet checksum" of that string, as a letter.

#### Example

Let's say we have the string *"helloworld"*. With `a = 0`, `b = 1`, `c = 2` ... `z = 25`, we can replace all of the letters with numbers:

```
h  e  l  l  o  w  o  r  l  d
7  4  11 11 14 22 14 17 11 3
```

Now, we can sum these:

```
7+4+11+11+14+22+14+17+11+3 = 114
```

If we mod this by 26, we get:

```
114 % 26 = 10
```

Now, using the same numbering system as before, get the 10th letter, `k`. This is our answer.

#### Test cases

```
Input          Output

helloworld     k
abcdef         p
codegolf       h
stackexchange  e
aaaaa          a
```

**This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25262/114446)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ADIkOè
```

Input as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0cUz2//wiv//o5UylHSUUoE4B4rzgbgcShdBxVKUYgE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVw6H9Hl4hs/8Mr/uv8j1bKSM3JyS/PL8pJUdJRSkxKTklNAzKS81NS0/NzQMziksTk7NSK5IzEvPRUkBoQUIoFAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
A       # Push the lowercase alphabet
 D      # Duplicate it
  I     # Push the input-list
   k    # Get the index of each character in the (top) alphabet
    O   # Sum these together
     è  # (Modular 0-based) index it into the alphabet
        # (after which this character is output as result)
```

Answer (score 9):

## Excel (ms365), <s>59</s>, 58 bytes

-1 Thanks to [@TheThonnu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114446/the-thonnu)

```
=CHAR(MOD(SUM(CODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1))+7),26)+97)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can change the `-97` to `+7` (as some other people have done in their answers)

Comment: @TheThonnu, you are right, but only the 1st one.

Comment: Yes, I meant the first one.

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 51 bytes

```javascript
s=>(B=Buffer)([B(s).map(c=>t+=c+7,t=0)|97+t%26])+''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc69DoIwFAXg3adoSAxtqmAcJA5l4DWMQ73cglK5hNafwXevEtABz/zlnHPRd@2gP3d@3VKJwajgVM4LVdyMwV7wQ8GdSK6646ByLxXIbOXVRrz2mfTL7e4oZBwHoNaRxcRSxQ2ParSWHtTbMmKMCcHSlDWLGdInKNEMgP1QN0fwOVWRndiI6jlyXkODT6h1W2E0IvybG/Jdm5p0eAM)

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
2Y2j97-sQ)
```

[Try it online!](https://matl.io/?code=2Y2j97-sQ%29&inputs=helloworld&version=22.7.4) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N8o0ijL0ly3OFDzv0vI/4zUnJz88vyinBSuxKTklNQ0ruT8lNT0/Jw0ruKSxOTs1IrkjMS89FSuRBAAAA).

#### Explanation

```
2Y2j97-sQ)
2Y2         % Push predefined literal: string 'abc···xyz'
            % STACK: 'abc···xyz'
   j        % Take input as a string
            % STACK: 'abc···xyz', 'helloworld'
    97-     % Push 97 (ASCII code of 'a'), and subtract element-wise
            % STACK: 'abc···xyz', [7 4 11 11 14 22 14 17 11 3]
       s    % Sum
            % STACK: 'abc···xyz', 114
        Q)  % Add 1, and use as index (1-based, modular). Implicit display
            % STACK: 'k'
```

Comment: Please can you add an explanation?

Comment: @TheThonnu Done!

Answer (score 5):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 68 bytes

```go
func(s string)(t int){for _,r:=range s{t+=int(r)-97}
return t%26+97}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hY9NasMwEIX3OoUQBCSSdNFF_kC7HCA3KIosOSayFGbGScH0JNmYQu_TrW8TOfHamc0wzON9791_y9T1_GLs2ZSO16aKrKovCehD-JoEuxrgqP8a8stNv_dNtBI5ElSxVJJ4FUm1PgH_WsBOg4nZBFua6_yQoJbb9Q8DRw1ETrPP1Tzfo9f_4PUESsVbhjstTi6EdEsQCsEOmUAhSlyMNOklKqUYamGOtnB-WmNT4coU3qiQcnH3bU9D8DfQYSYkY6-ue-0H)

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, <s>60</s> 48 bytes

```
FromLetterNumber[Tr[LetterNumber@#-1]~Mod~26+1]&
```

[View it on Wolfram Cloud!](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/ec33c9bc-7802-4cb5-ace8-cd76d01dae4e)

*-12 bytes thanks to [JSorngard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88906/jsorngard)!*

Comment: [-12 bytes](https://tio.run/##Xc2xCsIwEIDhPY8RwaVxqIOLBpycVBzcjhvS9NoE20bSE4VSX722KCLeTf8Hx9WGHdWGvTVDoYddDPWemCkeb3VGEc4Rfns7W6T4PIT8uVwlKc4HppataanVXScdVVW4h1jlUsmL7JXopMlsTsXY13fbkFMZqkncW1o29kIP60xT0sj0OZxmTCP7fi12IYLXqfIbvaemZLf9flY@SZQ4Rd8wiAK@DuARAVJE1Ppfl4hi3OEF "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online") if we avoid `StringLength` with some arithmetic tricks

Answer (score 5):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>142</s> 126 bytes

```
,[>++++++++[-<------------>]<-[->>>>+<<<<],]>>>>>+++++[->+++++<]>+<<[>+>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-]>>>>++++++++[-<++++++++++++>]<+.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxdCoAwDIMPtNUTlF6k9MFfFIeDgXj8Gp3Ivpe0SZuh9NuxnOPuHlXChxJTgxiTkoDAwKLJu9TTqmxPiAqBATVRxmzwEJH9D7U@NKA@dO7rnFK@cknTDQ)

Edit: -16 bytes due to common sense. Remembered I didn't have to load 97 into its own cell before adding/subtracting.

My first time golfing in brainfuck! Here's the ungolfed code for your viewing displeasure:

```
,					GET EACH CHARACTER IN THE INPUT
[
	>++++++++[-<------------>]<-	SUBTRACT 97 (8 TIMES 12 PLUS 1) FROM CELL 0
	[->>>>+<<<<]			ADD CELL 0 TO CELL 4
	, 				INPUT TO CELL 0
]
>>>>					GO TO CELL 4
>+++++[->+++++<]>+<<			LOAD 26 (5 TIMES 5 PLUS 1) INTO CELL 6
[>+>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-]		TAKE CELL 4 MOD CELL 6
>>>					GO TO RESULT IN CELL 7
>++++++++[-<++++++++++++>]<+		ADD 97 (8 TIMES 12 PLUS 1) TO CELL 7
.					DISPLAY
```

Comment: As stated in some other answers, you can probably save some bytes by replacing the "-97" by "+7" (because 97+7 = 104 and 104%26=0).

Comment: @F.Carette I tried to do that by just changing the third line of the ungolfed code to `+++++++`, but that started giving me the wrong answer somehow.

Comment: Looks like you suffer overflow, current code fail `zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz` (assuming another answer is correct)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) v4.2.0, <strike>63</strike> 59

*-4 thanks to Dominic van Essen*

```
\(x,l=letters)l[(sum(match(el(strsplit(x,"")),l)-1)%%26)+1]
```

The input string `x` is parsed as characters, and `match` is used to retrieve the index of each character in the `letters` builtin, minus one to convert from 1-based to 0-based.

Comment: Nice approach.  However, generally 'code golf' assumes that you need to include the code to 'receive' the string that you're being given, rather than assuming it's already been stored inside a variable whose name you know (as ```x``` here).  For R, this typically involves using ```scan(,'')``` , or defining a function that accepts the string as a parameter (here this would add 4 bytes [like this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHK5IzU5Ozi0lzbpaUlaboWN51jNCp0cmxzUktKUouKNXOiNYCSGjmJBQU5lRrFJUXFBTmZJUAlSkqaOrmJJckZOjma0dGGsbG6hpqqqkZmmtqGsRCjtsGM1lDKSM3JyS_PL8pJUdKESC5YAKEB))

Comment: (and, by the way, ```match``` is vectorized, so you can shave-off a few bytes by skipping the ```lapply``` altogether [like this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHK5IzU5Ozi0lzbpaUlaboWN61jNCp0cmxzUktKUouKNXOiNYCSGrmJJckZGqk5GsUlRcUFOZklQEVKSpqaOjmauoaaqqpGZprahrEQI7bBjNRQykjNyckvzy_KSVHShEguWAChAQ)...)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen again, thanks for the tips! I wasn't aware of the "\" function shorthand -- it seems that's new with R 4.1. Very handy indeed.

Answer (score 5):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
⟨c97%⟩¦Σ26%97+c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//9H8FcmW5qqP5q88tOzcYiMzVUtz7eT//4tLEpOzUyuSMxLz0lMB)

Pretty standard implementation of what the challenge asks.

I was able to save a byte thanks to the golfing advice given by
Dominic van Essen!

### Explained

```
⟨c97%⟩¦Σ26%97+c
⟨    ⟩¦           # To each letter in the input {
 c97%            #  modulo the character code by 96
                 #  }
       Σ26%      # Get the sum of that list and modulo 26
          97+c   # and add 97 to turn it back into an ascii letter
```

Comment: Why use mod 96 + decrement instead of just mod 97?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I'm not the best at figuring out modulos just yet. Thanks for the golfing advice!

Comment: -1 byte: `⟨c7+⟩¦Σ26%97+c`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 43 bytes

-1 byte from @Arnauld

```python
lambda s:chr(sum(ord(c)+7for c in s)%26+97)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr3gJd/FWkBT0ky6miYK6shrR622mfj1QWYY/zpFMvpwRbbeBoT0ZiB1YVNoTCytiEQ2neVWbxlE5lg4eZLhTopc4OYk4fg)

Comment: No need for `f=`, just put it in the header code (saving you 2 bytes).

Comment: The `+7` is really clever! I had the exact same solution, except I used `-97` instead.

Comment: @TheThonnu can you explain how 'header code' is valid for not being able to call this function now? How does this work and how is this valid for a code golf?

Comment: @Jeroentetje3 - there's a rule somewhere on https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com where it says that for `lambda` functions in Python, you can name it in the header. If you look at some other Python answers as well, you'll see this convention.

Comment: @Jeroentetje3 - I found it: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1503/114446: functions do not need to be named.

Comment: @TheThonnu So it is indeed just a convention and not something technical. Thank you for the clarification and also the effort for the link.

Comment: @Jeroentetje3 - yes, you might not see this on other Code Golf sites. You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`,  <sup><s>25</s></sup>   24 bytes

```factor
[ 7 v+n Σ 26 mod 97 + ]
```

-1 byte thanks to some black magic from Arnauld!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBDoIwFET3nGJC4orEhQuJegDjxo1xhSzq7y8lQgttARPjabyPV6qis5iXSd4oQcG6eD4djvstlHWtCKE2Fb7Uv1oOpiYr@T9Gnn2PfoLnfmBD7LFLkn56QHPT2Mm6RkJcSbLC/Ktso@CDoBvfSQtTMcQcPGOBHGNm8H5htUZrJTY5MpSxFR0KpAu6mBSdq01QKMGCdPwA)

```
     ! "helloworld"
7    ! "helloworld" 7
v+n  ! { 111 108 115 115 118 126 118 121 115 107 }
Σ    ! 1154
26   ! 1154 26
mod  ! 10
97   ! 10 97
+    ! 107
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
O+7S‘ịØa
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of characters and yields a character.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99f2zz4UcOMh7u7D89I/P//f3J@Smp6fk4aAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99f2zz4UcOMh7u7D89I/P9w95bD7Y@a1kT@/58BlM8vzy/KSeFKTEpOSU3jSs5PSU3Pz0njKi5JTM5OrUjOSMxLT@VKBAEA).

#### How?

```
O+7S‘ịØa - Link: list of characters, Message
O        - ordinals (Message)
 +7      - add seven (vectorises)
   S     - sum
    ‘    - increment
      Øa - "abc...xyz"
     ị   - index into (1-based and modular)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 37 bytes

```
explode|map(.-97)|[add%26+97]|implode
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z@1oiAnPyW1JjexQENP19JcsyY6MSVF1chM29I8tiYzFyz7/39Gak5Ofnl@UU4KV2JSckpqGlcyUDw9PyeNq7gkMTk7tSI5IzEvPZUrEQT@5ReUZObnFf/XDQIA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 27 bytes

```
{chr sum(.ords X-97)%26+97}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcHRCoJAEAXQX7mIRhH10IMipN/Rm6y7My40NjFblIjfvtE5TzKp87xgx@jy6qMhvef9WS0k3E5tc6gu9bFttpzcgqIc0PVYGeWwFWA1XCOJ6EdNAtzoAzG8BppUGOnl/J2@PrrHRHB/ff4B)

Answer (score 4):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 7 bytes (14 nibbles)

```
+%+.$-$;'a'26
```

```
   .            # map over 
    $           # the input:
     -          #   subtract
        'a'     #   the letter 'a'
       ;        #   (and save it)
      $         #   from each letter
                #   (which gives its 0-based index)
  +             # now sum this list
 %         26   # apply modulo-26
+               # and add back the saved letter 'a'
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>36</s> 26 bytes

```julia
!s=sum([s...].-'a')%26+'a'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BDoIwEEX3nGKYYGwjNtGFO05CXNR2gEptCQORePlaeJv/Fi/579U7fdtSKrnh9SNaVko91fWsz/J0f1zypi7OILgGLcEF@LlJCBzI@/iNs7dYA@qXsdTtZqKlPvrDedFmpM0MOvR0ZDso6xbHaSCN@5UsIDPNLiw@CKwYKlGyhNyXDE2TXwsKNv0B)

-10 MarcMush

Comment: -10 bytes by adding and subtracting chars directly `!s=sum([s...].-'a')%26+'a'`

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
`c$97+26!+/97!
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs0pIVrE01zYyU9TWtzRX5OJKi1bKSM3JyS/PL8pJUYoF8ROTklNS0yDs5PyU1PT8HCivuCQxOTu1IjkjMS89FaoYBJRiAZ5hG88=)

*-2 bytes thanks to coltim!*

Explanation:

```
`c$97+26!+/97!  Main function. Takes implicit input
           97!  Modulo by 97 to each character in the string
                to convert them into the 0..25 system
                (In K, every character in a string is also an ASCII charcode)
         +/     Sum
      26!       Modulo by 26
   97+          + 97 to each of them to convert them back to ASCII charcode
`c$             And convert them back to characters
```

Comment: You don't need the `'` on the `-97+` (it will "vectorize" automatically); additionally, `-97+` can be swapped out for `97!`

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)

```ruby
->a{(a.sum{_1.ord+7}%26+97).chr}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3FXTtEqs1EvWKS3Or4w318otStM1rVY3MtC3NNfWSM4pqIer2F5SWFCu4RauWR2copCrkAGG-QjkQFwFZKbGxEFULFkBoAA)

Comment: @Arnauld Nice! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
øA‹∑₄%›øA
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDuEHigLniiJHigoQl4oC6w7hBIiwiIiwic3RhY2tleGNoYW5nZSJd)

```
øA‹∑₄%›øA
øA          Letter to number (1-indexed)
  ‹         Decrement each value in list
   ∑        Sum it up
    ₄%›     Modulo by 26 and increment
       øA   Number to letter
```

Comment: `øA‹∑₄%›øA` is shorter

Comment: @lyxal oh wow I didn't know decrement vectorises by default

Comment: [6 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDuEHiiJFrYWkiLCIiLCJzdGFja2V4Y2hhbmdlIl0=) by porting the 05AB1E answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [simply](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/simply), 76 bytes

It is a pretty long one...

Creates an anonymous function that outputs the expected result.

```
fn($S){$X=0each$S as$C;$X=&add($X&sub(&ord($C)97))out!ABCL[$_=&mod($X,26)];}
```

Yes, that's right, I'm assigning the result of `&mod` into a variable.
Without it, it gives a syntax error, because ... I made mistakes in the compiler...

## Using the code

Simply call the function.

```
$fn = fn($S){$X=0each$S as$C;$X=&add($X&sub(&ord($C)97))out!ABCL[$_=&mod($X,26)];}

// should output "h"
call $fn("codegolf");
```

## Ungolfed

Somewhat code-y looking:

```
$fn = fn($string) => {
    $sum = 0;
    each $string as $char {
        $sum = &add($sum, &sub(&ord($char), 97));
    }
    
    $index = call &mod($sum, 26);
    
    echo !ABCL[$index];
}
```

Plain English-ish/Pseudo-code looking:

```
Set $fn to an anonymous function($string).
Begin.
    Set $sum to 0.
    
    Loop through $string as $char.
    Begin.
        Set $sum to the result of calling the function &add(
            $sum,
            Call the function &sub(
                Call the function &ord($char),
                97
            )
        ).
    End.
    
    Set $index to the result of calling the function &mod($sum, 26).
    
    Show the value !ABCL[$index].
End.
```

Both versions do exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;x!aC gC
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O3ghYUMgZ0M&input=WwpbImgiLCJlIiwibCIsImwiLCJvIiwidyIsIm8iLCJyIiwibCIsImQiXQpbImEiLCJiIiwiYyIsImQiLCJlIiwiZiJdClsiYyIsIm8iLCJkIiwiZSIsImciLCJvIiwibCIsImYiXQpbInMiLCJ0IiwiYSIsImMiLCJrIiwiZSIsIngiLCJjIiwiaCIsImEiLCJuIiwiZyIsImUiXQpbImEiLCJhIiwiYSIsImEiLCJhIl0KXS1tUg)

Input as an array of characters.

Explanation:

```
;x!aC gC
;        # C = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 x       # Compute the following for each character, then sum the results:
  !aC    #  Find its index in C
      gC # Get the character at that index in C (wrapping)
```

You can also rearrange things [like this](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O0NnVXghYUM&input=WwpbImgiLCJlIiwibCIsImwiLCJvIiwidyIsIm8iLCJyIiwibCIsImQiXQpbImEiLCJiIiwiYyIsImQiLCJlIiwiZiJdClsiYyIsIm8iLCJkIiwiZSIsImciLCJvIiwibCIsImYiXQpbInMiLCJ0IiwiYSIsImMiLCJrIiwiZSIsIngiLCJjIiwiaCIsImEiLCJuIiwiZyIsImUiXQpbImEiLCJhIiwiYSIsImEiLCJhIl0KXS1tUg) for a different 8 byte solution which works almost exactly the same way.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 14 bytes

```
ạ+₇ᵐ+%₂₆+₉₇g~ạ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GuhdqPmtofbp2grfqoqelRUxuQ2wkUSa8DSv3/r5QEU6z0PwoA)

#### Explanation

```
ạ                 String to char codes
 +₇ᵐ              Add 7 to each code (a <-> 97 becomes 104 = 0 (mod 26))
    +             Sum
     %₂₆          Mod 26
        +₉₇       Add 97
           g      Wrap into a list
            ~ạ    Char code to string
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 7 bytes

```
L7*SvOq
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9/HXCu4zL/w////SsUlicnZqRXJGYl56alKAA)

```
         The input is implicitly converted into bytecodes on the stack.
L7*      Push the length of the input, times 7.
   S     Push the sum of the stack.
    vO   Send this to the 'output stack'.
      q  Index into the ASCII lowercase alphabet (mod 26) and print the result.
```

Pushing 7 times the length comes from the fact that `a` has bytecode 97, and \$ -97 \equiv 7 \ (\text{mod} \, 3) \$. So it's equivalent to subtracting 97 from each bytecode.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 132 bytes

```java
interface T{static void main(String[]a){int i=a[0].length(),s=0;for(;i-->0;s+=a[0].charAt(i)+7);System.out.print((char)(97+s%26));}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczRCoIwFIDhV9lNcIYp0kUSo6BnsDvx4qBTj81NtpMR4rMvo@vv5x9xwdTN2o7tM0ayrH2HjRaPNTAyNWJx1IoJyULJnmxf1SjXvRN0xSqvM6NtzwPIY7jmqnMeFKXpLVch@XszoL8zkEwKqcpPYD1l7sXZvM8Y4McSLkUSDqezlGrbYoyDNsa9nTftFw)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

### C# (.Net 6), 64 bytes

```
int i=0,j=0;for(;i<a.Length;)j+=a[i++]-97;return(char)(97+j%26);
```

[Try it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KaXcug)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 19 bytes

```
(26|+/)&.(_97+3&u:)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxWcPIrEZbX1NNTyPe0lzbWK3UShMic9NVkys1OSNfyUAhTc1OQT0jNScnvzy_KCdF3Vo9MSk5JTUNyEjOT0lNz88BMYtLEpOzUyuSMxLz0lNBakBAHWLYggUQGgA)

```
(26|+/)&.(_97+3&u:)
       &.            NB. F&.G y applies G⁻¹(F(G x)) to y, rank is decided by G
         (_97+3&u:)  NB. fork converting str to char codes and subtracting 97 from each
(26|+/)              NB. fork that sums the arg and mods the result by 26
                     NB. +/ can be used because u: operates on y as a whole
                     NB. The inverse of G in this case would be to add 97 to
                     NB. the result of F and then convert char code to str
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Bits](https://github.com/nayakrujul/bits), 130 bits = 16.25 bytes

```js
1110000111000001110001011111110111010100000001100111110101011100011000000110001011001101101110000000110100111001111101010111111100
```

This was very painful.

#### Explanation

```js
11100001   // Get a string input
1100000    // Push 0 to the stack [this will be our running sum]
11100010   // For each character in the input string:
111111101  //   Get ord(c)
1101010    //   Add [to the running sum]
000000     //   Separator so the numbers don't get joined together
1100111    //   Push 7
1101010    //   Add [to the running sum]
11100011   // ENDFOR
000000     // Separator so the numbers don't get joined together
1100010    // Push 2
1100110    // Push 6 [this gets joined into 26]
1101110    // Mod our running sum by 26
000000     // Separator so the numbers don't get joined together
1101001    // Push 9
1100111    // Push 7 [this gets joined into 97]
1101010    // Add [to the result of the mod]
111111100  // Get chr(x)
           // [implicit output of the item on the top of the stack]
```

#### Output

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>44</s> <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```r
letters[sum(utf8ToInt(scan(,""))+7)%%26+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pye1pCS1qDi6uDRXo7QkzSIk3zOvRKM4OTFPQ0dJSVNT21xTVdXITNsw9n9Gak5Ofnl@UU7KfwA)

(or [38 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHK5IzU5Ozi0lzbpaUlaboWN9ViNCo0c1JLSlKLiqOB4hpAYYuQfM-8EqC4trmmqqqRmbZhLET1NphuDaWM1Jyc_PL8opwUJU2I5IIFEBoA) as a function in [R](https://www.r-project.org/) ≥ 4.1).

Answer (score 2):

## [Thon (Symbols)](https://github.com/nayakrujul/thon-symbols) <sup>`s` flag</sup>, 10 [bytes](https://github.com/nayakrujul/thon-symbols/blob/main/Codepage.md)

```
$åị$Σ26%å`
```

#### Explanation

```
$åị$Σ26%å`   // (implicit input as a string)
$  $         // For each character in the input string:
 åị          //   Get the index in the alphabet
             // (implicitly create a list of all of these indexes)
    Σ        // Sum the list
     26%     // Mod by 26
        å`   // Get that letter of the alphabet
             // (implicit output)
```

Comment: -1? Please explain? It works fine for all test cases.

Comment: My guess is that the downvote is for the challenge poster immediately posting their own solution.

Comment: @Adám thanks. I thought that was fine. I won't do that in future, then.

Comment: Well, it *is* fine, especially when doing so in a lesser known language. It is just my guess that the downvoter expressed their personal opinion.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 74 bytes

```python
from string import*
f=lambda s,l=ascii_lowercase:l[sum(map(l.index,s))%26]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DczBCsIwDADQu1/Ri6yV4UHBg7AvEZG4ti6QNCWpuH193f3x6tYWKdfeswo7a4rl45CraDsd8kTA7wjORprAZsQXyS/pDJbu9LAve4bq6YwlpnW0EI6X27PXPWk@@2FJtHtRikMI/Q8)

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [`golfing-shortcuts`](https://github.com/nayakrujul/golfing-shortcuts), 47 bytes

```python
lambda S:Sl[s(m(Sl.index,S))%26]
from s import*
```

(Is this one a competitive answer?)

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$10\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 8.231 bytes

```
ica%26S+7C
```

Using [Arnauld's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) logic. Accepts a list of characters

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJpY2ElMjZTKzdDIiwiW3MsdCxhLGMsayxlLHgsYyxoLGEsbixnLGVdIl0=)

```
ica%26S+7C
         C # str -> char code, vectorises
       +7  # add 7 to each item
      S    # sum
   %26     # sum % 26
 ca        # lowercase alphabet
i          # index intro ca using result
```

## Alternate \$13\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 10.701 bytes

```
ica%26SM'lxca
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJpY2ElMjZTTSdseGNhIiwiW3MsdCxhLGMsayxlLHgsYyxoLGEsbixnLGVdIl0=)

```
ica%26SM'lxca
           ca  # lowercase alphabet
          x    # input
       M'l     # map find over x where we look for each char in ca, returns index
      S        # sum
   %26         # sum % 26
ica            # index into ca using the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 41 bytes

```sh
a=(+##${(s..)^1}+7)
<<<${(#)$((a%26+97))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1LCsIwGIT3PYWQCvkJFHRhEeJVhLyjjY021dZIzx6TA@RbzQNmYrBJY8CJXTBBqP3h0HVwPWykh4ZSmgMELcZsfzyRcw@wJWgavbPKOb/4yclsGBdS6SyEl8p4V2SYmRjUKiwbjcr@tahp/r5v/umGuzVaBhZX8eHjowxUySWvUh6r5DJWSX8)

`(s..)`plit, `^` RC-style expand as `+##${1[1]}+7 +##${1[2]}+7 ...`. Then `(#)` evaluate the expression as character codes.

Answer (score 2):

## ARM Thumb machine code, 18 bytes

```
61 20 04 c9 61 3a 10 44 fb d5 1a 38 fd d2 7b 30
70 47
```

Assembler source:

```c
    .syntax unified
    .arch armv7-a
    .thumb
    .globl alpha_checksum
    .thumb_func
    // Input: r1: null terminated UTF-32LE string
    // Output: r0
    // Clobbers: r0-r2
alpha_checksum:
    // Initial accumulator. Start at 'a' to cancel the checksum
    // loop adding '\0' - 'a' when the null terminator is reached.
    movs   r0, #'a'
.Lloop:
    // Load character, increment pointer
    ldmia  r1!, {r2}
    // Subtract 'a' to convert to a number, set flags
    // In the case of the null terminator, this will result in
    // -'a', which ends the loop condition below.
    subs   r2, #'a'
    // Add to the checksum, without setting the flags
    add    r0, r2
    // Loop if the subs didn't return negative,
    // which happens only with the null terminator.
    bpl    .Lloop
.Lend:
    // Calculate (checksum % 26) - 26 using a naive subtraction loop
.Lmodulo:
    // Subtract 26
    subs   r0, #26
    // Loop while it was >= 26
    bhs    .Lmodulo
    // Add 26 to correct the modulo, and 'a' to convert to ASCII.
    adds   r0, #'a' + 26
    // Return
    bx     lr
```

This can be called from C using a dummy parameter to place `ptr` in `r1`.

`ptr` is expected to be a pointer to a null terminated UTF-32LE string.

```c
char32_t alpha_checksum(int dummy, const char32_t *ptr);
```

Comment: I was curious how much it saves to take UTF32 / `wchar_t` input: The `ldmia` is only 2 bytes (`04 c9`), but a `11 f8 01 2b     ldrb  r2, [r1], #1` post-increment byte load is 4 bytes.  So a `char*` version would be 2 bytes longer.  Passing a length as another arg would also cost extra bytes, since an implicit-length C string allows folding the check into a `subs` we're already doing.  And there's no `[R1, R2]` addressing mode with pre-decrement of one register.

Comment: Not that it matters for code size, but I think it would be more idiomatic to use `bge` or `bhs` to keep looping while the input character was `>= 'a'` (signed or unsigned), rather than branching on the sign of the subtraction result.  `bpl` is different from `bge` if there's signed overflow.  In this case you could think about it as doing a (potentially signed-wrapping) subtraction and then checking the sign of the result, but it seems like a bad habit vs. using the flags result of `subs` like it was a `cmp`.  Probably not worth editing the answer to change, though.  Nice one.

Comment: Yeah I could also do bge or bhs, I chose bpl because I was emphasizing the fact that it will end up adding a negative.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, good point.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 46

```c
t;f(char*s){for(t=0;*s;)t+=*s++-97;t=t%26+97;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/LTsMwEDwnX7EERXLiFFUcQMikX1Bx4wQVStfOQ6QOsjdQqcq3BzsuqlD3sJode2dmcdUgzjOJmmFbmdxmp3owjMq1yK3IiJe55Xz19CiopPT@gTs0zbedxn6UCp4tSanqu3YT/@O6wVNxpwkOVaeBeVSZBgvwNpA7/J3BKQZXgSFlCSur7NsOSvcSJa3q@@FnML1MCjdWe3RWC8RBqmbow2Cpwk91dCq6UeGnL49eXrfbxWISFydLBu14CIzPRfjRyaOIF8JdDywwLsZawCVXYHdwU4IXFudFzv0h0VnWLdXsaicTcfRlnFnNktTCagMpvuukuFYv/vJlIeC0dKNoNNrFiaf5Fw)

Comment: [41](https://tio.run/##ZU9bS8MwFH5uf8WxMkh6ESfiqLXzDwzffHJD6kl6wa6VnFQHo7@9Js1kyM5D@M6XfJdgUiFOU8mwLlRI/Eh5SM/pKmIhRSWjaMmTZXrPF3cPj@kqG6frpsN2EBKeSAshy5t67f/jmt5SftNp2BdNB8yiQlUYg82A0OBvDkcfzDhGS9JYkKS3HeTmxgtq2bb9T69aEcRmLT7QRM0QeyGrvnUL6QI/5cG4dJV0L@1Y9PK62cwRY3ZOIq2Qhr1jbC@N7404ZP5MlL0C5hhT4zaDcy/H7uAqB2ucnYRRZD/inWyNqGQXGp753pcyYSULFgTJGha47YL40j3@68ddwXE@ldSD6kwdf5x@AQ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: You can save one more by changing `char` to `int`.

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZU9dT4QwEHyGX7FiLuHTeMZ4wcr5B4hvPnkXg0sLxB6YbtFLLvx2bAE15vahnZ3tzkwxqRDHUfhNq0MKTpSF9JhuIj@kSPgUrYNknd4Gq5u7@3TDhvGyaVH2JYcH0mXJxVW9df9xTWcp18jBoWhasMJQqApjwLpQEBr8GcDJBVN2FmpOGgvi9LKHzAyc3Ku5lN1Xp2TpxbYv3tB4zRi7kledXDrSBb7zo5FuK748tmXh03OeTzYDm67Jn7RC6g/s11/ja1MemTsRolPgz4zJcs3gL9zM7uEiAyvMlsUosp9xFlmzJPyznYC5zocyZsL3VpIg2cIKd60Xn8vHPwGDOeEwnYrrXrUmjzuM3w)

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 65 bytes

```clj
(defn a[s](char(+(mod(apply + (map #(- % 97)(map int s)))26)97)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY4xDsIwDEV3TmEFVbJVsTCAOAswGCdtgTSOkiLg9CEwE29@78v@4vX2SK4UtG4IwMd8Rpk4YY@zWuQY/Rt6wJkjrHEDHRz29NuuYYFMRNsdVURUMKbKBjCdnIIBZDCT816fmrw1RKs/Ab5I/duQotaN6ls6Lyx396ptw@ha979TXfkA)

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn alpha-checksum [s]
  (char (+ (mod (apply + (map #(- % 97) (map int s))) 26) 97)))
```

Comment: You can remove the space in `+ (` for -1, and you can use `fn` instead of `defn a` (using an anonymous function) to save another 4, and then combine the two `map` statements to save a bunch more - [TIO](https://tio.run/##dY6xDgIxDEN3viIqOikRYmEA8S3AENL2Dght1R4Cvr70durJ0rNsi8b7K7uK1nngij6cygVl4owbfEaLnJJ@oXlOsMYt3sIMAx0PVIh2@8UQVVphyo14MIOcgwFkMJNTje@Y1Rr6G@CrtNUOlGjdGLWHy8zycJ92NIyu17@osfoD)

Comment: And off of that, you can save one more byte by using a `#` lambda for the outer function and `fn` on the inner one (which allows removing a whitespace): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY6xDgIxDEN3vqIqOikRYmEA8S3AENL2DghNVQ5Rvr4UZurJ0rNss@j1mX0F54OhugSeKMMK7uqAUpK3aZ4ShHgoJ1jDJc6m4H6HOCButj9XcQEpNxKMHfgYrQEydvIi@tIszuLfAJ25jXYgq/OjSg8/ZuKbL@1sHH2v/6vG6gc "Clojure – Try It Online")

Comment: And off of that (sorry lol), you can save one more byte using a trick from the other answers (changing `-97` to `+7`): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY4xDsIwDEV3ThEFVbLFxgDiLMBgHKcFTBKFIsLpg9npn57@s2yz5turSocg0VFfA09UYQOPHIBK0Y8zpgIxHdvZ@muaXcM94oC43eHBqOMKSjURnR/4lLwDcn4S1fzOVYPHvwN0Ybu5IDkHGbMu6edMfJdmv6ZRlvb/Yq5/AQ "Clojure – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 47 bytes

```
Fn.new{|s|(s.bytes.reduce{|x,y|x+7+y}+7)%26+97}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYuxCsMgGIT3PoUECorBoUNDh06FzoWMpYPR3yTUaFHbRGKe3cZb7uPjbnZg8o87pK75bpiBeU0@Yc@6GMAzB/IrYE1LHdNCGxo32pDj6UwvzZaVdQh7NBr0rAbQ2s7WaVnVFe@EBLWDsBJ6qwv6wMUbFjFw00PZlFQvgtYDQm30ASb2caMJuA179Uw5O932/8MWqZjgWmNPCDls@Q8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
§βΣＥＳ⌕βι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMOxxDMvJbVCI0lHIbg0V8M3sUDDM6@gtCS4BCidrqGpo@CWmZcCks7UBAHr//@LSxKTs1MrkjMS89JT/@uW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    Ｓ       Input string
   Ｅ        Map over characters
       ι    Current character
     ⌕      Find index in
      β     Predefined variable lowercase alphabet
  Σ         Take the sum
§           Cyclically indexed into
 β          Predefined variable lowercase alphabet
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 25 bytes

```
0T1>`l`L
+T`l__L`zlL_`^..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcFBCoAgEADA@/4jCAKpD3Tt4tFz7qarRouCBUWfN5qpfO2ZWtcv2EYzzSioYTAo1mp8RVtclWotsUi5SxUPtDnPAVzxHIsEOC9yBz8uUY4M9PsA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
0T1>`l`L
```

Uppercase all letters after the first.

```
+T`l__L`zlL_`^..
```

While there are at least two letters, repeatedly rotate the first letter backwards and the second letter forwards in the alphabet, however the first letter rotates back from `a` to `z` while the second letter drops off when it passes `Z`, allowing subsequent letters to be processed.

The `l` and `L` in the patters expand to the lowercase and uppercase alphabet respectively. The `_` in the source pattern is just a placeholder to allow the use of `l` and `L` in the destination pattern, while in the destination pattern it indicates that the character is to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 20 bytes

```
C(($+(7+A*a))%26+97)
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJDKCgkKyg3K0EqYSkpJTI2Kzk3KSIsIiIsIiIsImhlbGxvd29ybGQiXQ==)

Probably could be shorter, I feel like there are just way too many parentheses.

Comment: Hint: The preset variable `z` should be quite useful here.

Comment: @DLosc I literally tried that and it came out longer, I must be doing something horribly wrong

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 15 bytes

```
'a'+26|·+´-⟜'a'
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=Q2hlY2tzdW0g4oaQICdhJysyNnzCtyvCtC3in5wnYScKQ2hlY2tzdW0gImhlbGxvd29ybGQi)

```
'a'+26|·+´-⟜'a'
          -⟜'a'     # subtract 'a' from each letter of input
        +´          # sum
       ·            # (no-op to preserve train syntax)
    26|             # modulo 26
'a'+                # add 'a'
```

Answer (score 2):

### x86‑64 assembly machine code, 30 B

#### input

- unsigned length of string in 64‑bit register `rdi`
- address of string buffer in 64‑bit register `rsi`

#### code listing

```
 1                 alphabet_checksum:
 2 0000 6A61        push 'a'                    ; push(97)
 3 0002 58          pop rax                     ; pop(rax)
 4 0003 F7E7        mul edi                     ; edx○eax ≔ eax × edi
 5                  
 6 0005 F7D8        neg eax                     ; eax ≔ −eax; CF ≔ eax ≠ 0
 7 0007 7310        jnc .adjust                 ; if ¬CF then goto adjust
 8                 .sum:
 9 0009 0FB64C3EFF  movzx ecx, byte [rsi+rdi-1] ; ecx ≔ (rsi + rdi − 1)↑
10 000E 01C8        add eax, ecx                ; eax ≔ eax + ecx
11 0010 FFCF        dec edi                     ; edi ≔ edi − 1; ZF ≔ edi = 0
12 0012 75F5        jnz .sum                    ; if ¬ZF then goto sum
13                  
14 0014 6A1A        push 26                     ; push(26)
15 0016 5F          pop rdi                     ; pop(rdi)
16 0017 F7F7        div edi                     ; edx ≔ edx○eax mod edi
17                 .adjust:
18 0019 92          xchg eax, edx               ; eax ≔ edx
19 001A 83C061      add eax, 'a'                ; eax ≔ eax + 97
20 001D C3          ret
```

#### output

- alphabet checksum as ASCII character in 64‑bit register `rax`

#### limitations

- length of string must be ≤ 44,278,013, else the `mul` spills into `edx`, yet the algorithm relies on `edx` being `0` in the case of a zero-length string

Comment: So isn't that just 31 bytes (\$2^5 - 1 = 31\$)?

Comment: What about multiplying `edi` with -97? Later use `cdq` to clean `edx`, with half but still enough range

Comment: Also `imul eax, edi, -97` is only 3 byte

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 72 bytes

```javascript
([...s])=>String.fromCharCode(s.map(c=>t+=c.charCodeAt()+7,t=0)|t%26+97)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc6xDoIwEIDh3adoSEzaoMU4iA4lMTyCo3GoR1uQQknboIPvXiGgA954@XL/PXjPHdiq89v@GCQL@EopdTfCsou3VauotKbJS25zUwjsaMM7DCzzMQMK8/rsMYnTjWc78vbr/SE@pSSAaZ3RgmqjsMRRKbQ2T2N1ESGECEFJgurVAvE7FEKOAP1Qt0QwFJXRM5tQuUTOc6jFa/iwVSKakPjLjfOtzZd4@AA)

Comment: Any idea how to get this working also for inputs of size 1 without additional bytes?

Answer (score 2):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 77 characters

```
?=@set{s;@add{${s;};@add{@char-int{?};7}}}
\Z=@int-char{@add{@mod{$s;26};97}}
```

(Yepp. Arithmetic operations are a pain in Gema.)

Sample run:

```
bash-5.1$ echo -n helloworld | gema '?=@set{s;@add{${s;};@add{@char-int{?};7}}};\Z=@int-char{@add{@mod{$s;26};97}}'
k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/397WoTi1pLrY2iExJaVaBciohTAdkjMSi3Qz80qq7WutzWtra7liomwdgHxdkEQ1RE1uPlBPsbWRWa21JVDN//8ZqTk5@eX5RTkpAA)

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 54 bytes

```
$s.tochararray()|%{$r+=([char]$_)-97};[char]($r%26+97)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvUqxgq6AEYuaX5xflpCgBRfRK8pMzEosSi4oSKzU0a1SrVYq0bTWiQWKxKvGaupbmtdYQnoZKkaqRmbalueb//wA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 16 bytes

```
zPK$+(A*a-97)%26
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJ6UEskKyhBKmEtOTcpJTI2IiwiIiwiIiwiaGVsbG93b3JsZCJd)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 43 bytes

```hs
f s=['a'..]!!mod(sum[fromEnum c-97|c<-s])26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vcy9DoIwFAXgvU9x6QImlsFBYyKjo09AGK79oYT@EArRRH32Kigaz3Ryc@6nMbTSmBgVhKJMMc3zKkmsF1kYbal6b49utMDZfnfnBxaq1WYbLTYOCrDYnSDr@sYNkINaQUn1y/IX3xtB10DxzIVUU@NeyNqbuYcBeSuvXKOr5TybQitCboz8AJjSkrcBSzqyUJ@DJn8egCSz9/0AJOwRnw)

#### Same-length alternative:

```hs
f s=['a'..]!!mod(sum$do c<-s;1<$['b'..c])26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcxNDoIwEAXg/ZxiaEiQREh04UY4gicgLIa2UEJLCcVoYjx7BRSNb/UyP58i10mtva/R5UVEUZqWQWCs2LmrCYVFniXufMjCIqrmHS/j48kbanvM0dBwwd0wtv2EKdYxFkzNlr3ZUQu2R0YVF7JeGrdCNlav3U3EO3nnivpGrmdLWAnwSOAH4JIO3gZuGWCjPgMFfx6ihNX7fiBB8vQv)

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2), 36 bytes

```
;=sP;=i@O;Ws;=i+~-97iAs=s]sA+97%i 26
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PXNQOz1pQE87V3M7PWkrfi05N2lBcz1zXXNBKzk3JWkgMjYiLCJoZWxsb3dvcmxkIiwiMi4wIl0=)

I feel like you can golf better but i tried for awhile and gave up

Answer (score 2):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <del>26</del> 24 bytes

- -2 bytes thanks to @Eminga. I didn't want to change the input mode to stack though so I didn't use all the golfing potential. Also I wanted to exit properly and not just error.

```
0i:0(?v+7+2d*%!
o+"a"~<;
```

[Animated Version](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiMGk6MCg/dis3KzJkKiUhXG5vK1wiYVwifjw7IiwiaW5wdXQiOiJoZWxsb3dvcmxkIiwic3RhY2siOiIiLCJtb2RlIjoibnVtYmVycyJ9)

### Explanation:

```
0
```

Push 0, the starting value

```
i:0(?v
```

Check if the input is negative, if so go down.

```
+7+2d*%
```

Add 7+the input to the accumulator, then mod 26

```
!
```

Skip the 0 the second time, since the accumulator is already set

```
~"a"+o;
```

(Reversed in the program)
Print "a" + the accumulator.

Comment: You can save [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/31w7x9DWvkybS1UpUUk73y7FSOv///@6xRmpOTn55flFOSkA) by adding 7 to each char code and summing them before modding by 26.

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 11 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
+@a◿26/+-@a
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgK0Bh4pe_MjYvKy1AYQoKZiAiaGVsbG93b3JsZCIKZiAiYWJjZGVmIgpmICJjb2RlZ29sZiIKZiAic3RhY2tleGNoYW5nZSIKZiAiYWFhYWEi)

```
+@a◿26/+-@a
        -@a  # convert string to code points
      /+     # sum
   ◿26       # modulo 26
+@a          # add the letter a
```

Comment: The ```+@a``` ... ```-@a``` bugs me... it's quite annoying that ```⍜'-@a(◿26/+)``` is a byte longer...

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>76</s> 73 bytes

-3 thanks to @[ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

I think this is as much golf as you can get without using a completely different method. Other people <s>will probably prove me wrong the moment I hit "Post."</s> have in fact proven me wrong.

```cpp
#import<ios>
int f(char*s){int t=0;for(;*s;t+=*s++-97);putchar(t%26+97);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY5BCoMwEEXX9RTBUoiKULpoqdHeJZ0kKo1JSEZaEM9ujT1And2f/3h8cK5sAZbl2A/Oeqx7Gx5Jb5AoCh33ecimmLA5M2U9ZXlgWDR5KIryfsuYGzFiFE@XaxEf82oyoEchSXShl3z4CQfeG5qRKTkomnZSa/u2Xos0Y8khoKgqsCOSuiZbkEbotdhg/gQh1Q4QrJCt1XvQgBxe8rOON63csyHeH24myxc)

#### Ungolfed

We used `#import<ios>` so we can `putchar()`.

```cpp
int f(char* s) {
    int t = 0;                      // Running total
    for(;*s != 0;t += *s++ - 97);   // Loop through string until we get to null byte, add to running total
    putchar(t % 26 + 97);           // Add 97 to final result and print
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 29 bytes

```arturo
$[a][+97(sum map a=>[+7])%26]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?2aJrIX)

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 91 bytes

```
++[++[->+>+<<]>>[--<<+>>]<],[[-[->+<]>]>>>>>>>,]+[<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+<[-----.[>]]>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYtLCoAwDAUP9BpPEHKRkEUtVUuhCz/g7WN07/BWb5h5z20sV@nugMZIIGA2ESVihoixJVV6TdwhPpJB@Rdw1MGkYtG4H2cuvd5ly2OtDw)

```
++[++[->+>+<<]>>[--<<+>>]<]    Init memory with 1,2,3,...,127
,[[-[->+<]>]>>>>>>>,]          Reading each byte, move right that many steps
+[<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+< Go left 26 and check if empty
[-----.[>]]>]                  If not empty, give shift, output and halt
```

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL v18, 28 bytes*

```
{a[1+26|+/1-⍨(a←¯1∘⎕C⎕A)⍳⍵]}
```

Assuming that indices start from one (`⎕IO←1`).

<sup>________________

*: APL can be written in its own legacy charset (defined by `⎕AV`) instead of Unicode; therefore an APL program that only uses ASCII characters and APL symbols can be scored as 1 char = 1 byte.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ä⁻S⁺ÄL
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMyU4NCVFMiU4MSVCQlMlRTIlODElQkElQzMlODRMJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9aGVsbG93b3JsZCZmbGFncz0=)

##### Explanation

```python
Ä⁻S⁺ÄL  # Implicit input
Ä       # 1-based index in alphabet
 ⁻      # Decrement to make 0-indexed
  S     # Sum the resulting list
   ⁺    # Increment for 1-indexing
    Ä   # 1-based convert to letter
     L  # Lowercase it
        # Implicit output
```